# Execfile running the file twice when used with import

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-import, execfile

I want to have a textbox and a button in my GUI and on clicking the button, it should take the text and store it in a variable for some other file and run the other file.

I want the user to enter an access token and the GUI should save it in the global variable access_token of utilities.py
But when importing the function for setting the access token only, the file runs which I don't want until the button is clicked.
So, effectively the file is running twice.

This is my gui.py

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from utilities import setAccessToken

root = tk.Tk()

def callback():
    setAccessToken(E1.get())
    execfile('utilities.py')

E1 = Entry(root,bd = 5, width = 10)
E1.pack()
#similarly other GUI stuff with command = callback()

mainloop()
```

This is my utilities.py

```
access_token = ""
def setAccessToken(token):
    global access_token
    access_token = token

print 'Running Utilities : access_token =', access_token
```

My expected output is:

```
Running Utilities: access_token = my access token
```

But I am getting the output twice, that is:

```
Running Utilities: access_token =
Running Utilities: access_token = my access token
```

Is there any way in which I can stop the file utilities.py from running when I am importing it?

Comment: why not wrap  print 'Running Utilities : access_token =', access_token logic in a function and invoke that instead of execfile.This way you can also avoid the print during import

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of `execfile`?

Comment: There are some other buttons as well which should run some other files. That is why I need to use execfile.

Comment: Wrapping the code written in the files will be time consuming because I have a lot of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a python file, all the code in it will be executed. That's how python works. To prevent executing unwanted code, we should always use `__name__` like this:

```
access_token = ""
def setAccessToken(token):
    global access_token
    access_token = token

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Running Utilities : access_token =', access_token
```